# Retrieving data poin from API response

Tags: php

I cobbled together some PHP code that allows me get business data from Yelp API v.3

```html
$postData = "grant_type=client_credentials&".
    "client_id=MyClientIDl94gqHAg&".
    "client_secret=SomEcoDehIW09e6BGuBi4NlJ43HnnHl4S7W5eoXUkB";


// GET TOKEN
$curl = curl_init();

//set the url
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.yelp.com/oauth2/token");
//tell curl we are doing a post
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
//set post fields
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
//tell curl we want the returned data
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

if($result){
    $data = json_decode($result);
}

// GET RESTAURANT INFO
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/north-india-restaurant-san-francisco",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: Bearer ".$data->access_token
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

//close connection
curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

The output looks like this:

> {"id": "north-india-restaurant-san-francisco", "name": "North India Restaurant", "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/fIgAIMHGfWRF3I0JmagQ7A/o.jpg", "is_claimed": true, "is_closed": false, "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/north-india-restaurant-san-francisco?adjust_creative=qG_bVdazAjjAO1l94gqHAg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_lookup&utm_source=qG_bVdazAjjAO1l94gqHAg", "phone": "+14153481234", "display_phone": "(415) 348-1234", "review_count": 857, "categories": [{"alias": "indpak", "title": "Indian"}], "rating": 4.0, "location": {"address1": "123 Second St", "address2": "", "address3": "", "city": "San Francisco", "zip_code": "94105", "country": "US", "state": "CA", "display_address": ["123 Second St", "San Francisco, CA 94105"], "cross_streets": ""}, "coordinates": {"latitude": 37.787789124691, "longitude": -122.399305736113}, "photos": ["https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/howYvOKNPXU9A5KUahEXLA/o.jpg", "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/I-CX8nioj3_ybAAYmhZcYg/o.jpg", "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/uaSNfzJUiFDzMeSCwTcs-A/o.jpg"], "price": "$$", "hours": [{"open": [{"is_overnight": false, "start": "1000", "end": "2300", "day": 0}, {"is_overnight": false, "start": "1000", "end": "2300", "day": 1}, {"is_overnight": false, "start": "1000", "end": "2300", "day": 2}, {"is_overnight": false, "start": "1000", "end": "2300", "day": 3}, {"is_overnight": false, "start": "1000", "end": "0000", "day": 4}, {"is_overnight": false, "start": "1000", "end": "0000", "day": 5}, {"is_overnight": false, "start": "1000", "end": "2300", "day": 6}], "hours_type": "REGULAR", "is_open_now": true}], "transactions": ["delivery", "pickup"]}

How do I retrieve opening hour on Friday, for example? The day are 0 - 6, Monday - Sunday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You parse the json data and iterate over the entries:

```
function getOpeningHoursForDay($data,$day){
    $open_hours = $data['hours'][0]['open'];
    $n = count($open_hours);

    for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
        if($open_hours[$i]['day']==$day) // check if day matches
            return $open_hours[$i];
    }
    return null; // no matching day found, return null
}

function formatOpeningHour($hour){
    return substr($hour,0,2).':'.substr($hour,2); // convert 2300 to 23:00
}


$data = json_decode($response,true);
$friday_hours = getOpeningHoursForDay($data,4);
if(isset($friday_hours)){
    echo 'opened ' . formatOpeningHour($friday_hours['start']) . ' - ' .formatOpeningHour($friday_hours['end']);
}else{
    echo 'closed';
}
```